# how to add syntax highlighting and completion to textarea or contenteditable div

Tags: jquery

I have gone through the net seeking for solution to this problem but still can't find any. I am building a html editor in virtual studio. and I have created a wide open textarea. My problem is this, I want it to do code completion exactly as notepad ++. I want it to do syntax highlighting and code completion any time I type in dot (mainly code completion). I want to know if there is any javascript or jquery lib that can do mainly code completion for these three languages: Javascript, HTML, and Css from there I can be able to do the remnants work.

If anyone can assist me in any way I will truly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a very good resource called [Prism](http://prismjs.com/). It highlights very clearly, like Notepad. Or if you want on the fly you can use [Codemirror](http://codemirror.net/)

Comment: Yes codemirror supports that. You can check here https://codemirror.net/demo/complete.html